# How to verify that an $\mathbb F[G]$-module has an imprimitivity decomposition or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

> An $\mathbb F[G]$-module $V$ is said to have an imprimitivity decomposition $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k W_i$, if $ W_i $'s are subspaces of $V$ which are transitively permuted by the action of $G$. Otherwise we say that $V$ is a primitive $\mathbb F[G]$-module where $\mathbb F$ is a field and $G$ a finite group.

I was given the fact in class that the two-dimensional irreducible representations of the dihedral group of order eight: $D_8$ are imprimitive, whereas, the four-dimensional irreducible representations of the symmetric group $S_5$ are primitive. But I am having trouble verifying these facts probably because I do not understand what modules we are really considering. For instance, if the module for $D_8$ we are referring to is the direct sum of two copies of $2$-dimensional spaces with the two-dimensional similar irreducible representations, then I do not even think the group action permutes $W_1$ and $W_2$.

So I am asking for possible clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Also, we know that there is only one $2$-dimensional irreducible representation for $D_8$ up to similarity...

Comment: When we speak of a rep $V$ being imprimitive, we are talking about decompositions of $V$ *itself*, not direct sums of copies of $V$. So for instance, $D_8$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and by extension $\mathbb{C}^2$ if we wish) by the usual rotation and reflection matrices. This preserves the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $x$- and $y$-axis, both 1D subspaces. Note these subspaces are *not* subreps, they are not invariant. Instead, the elements of $D_8$ either swap the axes or fix them (not pointwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the group $D_8$, we can take the image of the representation to be generated by the matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\ {\rm and}\ \left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right).$$

Then $W_1$ and $W_2$ can be chosen to be the $1$-dimensional subspaces spanned by the two basis vectors. These are clearly interchanged by the first matrix and fixed by the second.

In general, a representation of $G$ is imprimitive with a decomposition into $k$ blocks, if and only if it is induced from a subgroup of $G$ of index $k$. That provides one way of testing for imprimitivity.

For example, $S_5$ has no subgroup of index $4$, so its $4$-dimensional representations cannot be imprimitive.